# Как не подключаться к базе данных MySQL каждый раз?

Tags: python, mysql, connection

**Доброго времени суток.**

Я начинающий разработчик и это мой первый вопрос на StackOverflow, мастерю бота на python с использованием СУБД MySQL, mysql.connector.

Сейчас я каждый раз подключаюсь к БД по мере того, когда мне нужно изменить базу,
можно-ли сделать это однажды и больше не повторять этот кусок кода каждый раз?

Кроме того, меня интересует, можно-ли вот так оставлять пароль в исходном коде бота, залив его на хостинг, безопасно ли это?

Далее код:

```
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda m: True)
def echo_all(message):
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    if message.text == 'Создать анкету':
        try:
            with connect(
                    host="localhost",
                    # user=input("Введите имя пользователя: "),
                    # password=getpass("Введите пароль: "),
                    user="newuser",
                    password="255****",
                    database="forms"
            ) as connection:
                select_forms_query = '''
                SELECT chat_id 
                FROM form
                '''
                get_user_form = f'''
                SELECT name, years_old, title
                FROM form 
                WHERE chat_id = {user_id}
                '''
                with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                    cursor.execute(select_forms_query)
                    result = cursor.fetchall()
                    if is_user_in_base(result, user_id):
                        cursor.execute(get_user_form)
                        user_form = cursor.fetchall()
                        user_form_out(user_form, user_id)
                    else:
                        print(user_id, "- user is not in database")
                        process_filling_form(user_id)
        except Error as e:
            print(e)
```

Как можно сократить этот участок `with connect (...) as connection (...)` ?

Comment: А что мешает создать функцию, возвращающую активное подключение?

Comment: @Namerek, сейчас попробовал вынести это в отдельную функцию, возвращаю connection и connection.cursor(), вызываю cursor.execute() в другой функции, и на этом моменте программа прекращает работу с ошибкой "mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 2055: Cursor is not connected". Если Вы знаете, как вернуть активное подключение из функции, я был бы Вам благодарен за наглядный пример.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
from pymysql import Connection

def connect() -> Connection:
    return Connection(
#        your connection params
    )
```

UPD